# Custom .svg google maps marker in Kotlin, Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, kotlin

I want to use a .svg file as a map marker. In MapsActivity.kt i wrote:

```
private fun  bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context: Context, vectorResId:Int):BitmapDescriptor {
    val vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId);
    vectorDrawable!!.setBounds(0, 0, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    val canvas =  Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

...and this:

```
mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getActivity(), R.drawable.marker3)))
```

"marker3" at the end is created as new vector asset. On running i get this error:

> C:.....\MyApplication3\app\src\main\java\com\example\myapplication3\MapsActivity.kt: (58, 115): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
>   public open fun getActivity(p0: Context!, p1: Int, @NonNull p2: Intent, p3: Int, @Nullable p4: Bundle?): PendingIntent! defined in android.app.PendingIntent
>   public open fun getActivity(p0: Context!, p1: Int, p2: Intent!, p3: Int): PendingIntent! defined in android.app.PendingIntent

Please help!

Full MapsActivity.kt:

```
   package com.example.myapplication3

import android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions


class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private fun  bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context: Context, vectorResId:Int):BitmapDescriptor {
    val vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId)
    vectorDrawable!!.setBounds(0, 0, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight())
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas =  Canvas(bitmap)
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas)
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
}

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}
 */


override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getActivity(), R.drawable.marker3)))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
}
```

}

Comment: `Exception` is not related to `VectorDrawable` it's related to `PendingIntent`. Check your code carefully.

Comment: I'am sorry, but I didn't understand :(

Comment: Add more details of `MapsActivity.kt`

Comment: Added full code in question. Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MapsActivity` should show compile time error as your call to `getActivity()` is wrong. Instead of using `getActivity()` used `this` as it is inside `Activity`. Check below:

```
mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(this, R.drawable. marker3)))
```

Comment: You are welcome @RobertZt, Please accept the answer